# play 2.6.x environment dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, playframework-2.0, production-environment

I am trying to find the mode (Dev vs Prod) of my play application. I have injected Environment as below:

```
public class Sample{
    @Inject
    private play.Environment environment;
```

and I am invoking the method as show below:

```
    public void methodName(){
        if(environment.isDev()) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

since the variable `environment` is uninitialized it throws a `NullPointerException` when I try to access it to call `isDev()` method.

How do I initialize the `environment` object? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use field injection, it won't work in a lot of cases.

```
public class Sample {
    @Inject
    public Sample(final Environment environment) {

    }
}
```

Second, how is Sample created ? You need to create it using dependency injection, else it won't work. If you need it, use :

```
bind(Sample.class).as(Singleton.class);
```

and then @Inject sample in another class. If it's not a singleton, bind() it differently